# How to create a texture2d from an array of pixels in DirectX11

Tags: textures, rendering, directx11

I currently have a ray-casting camera that holds an array of pixel colors (XMFLOAT4 color) that is 1024x768.

I am trying to create a Texture2D in DirectX11 that is also 1024x768 and simply copy over the pixels to the texture. I then want to apply the texture to a fullscreen quad to essentially display what geometry my rays are intersecting with.

```
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc = { 0 };
    textureDesc.Width = 1024;
    textureDesc.Height = 768;
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

    ID3D11Texture2D* fullScreenTexture = nullptr;
    ThrowIfFailed(mGame->Direct3DDevice()->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, nullptr, &fullScreenTexture), "ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D() failed.");
```

Assuming I have XMFLOAT4 pixels[1024][768]; //Filled in appropriately with colors.

I'm not sure where/how I would take my pixel data and apply it to the texture. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Attempting to set SubResource data to pixel array.